# Change grid setup with prompt() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Can the number of rows and squares be changed somehow after entering a number < 64 in the prompt? I don't want the size of "box_main" to be changed.
So basically only change the ratio of .square and .row and modify rows and columns.

jQuery:

```js
var rows = 16;
var columns = 16;
var $row = $("<div />", {
    class: 'row'
});
var $square = $("<div />", {
    class: 'square'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        $row.append($square.clone());
    }
  
    for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        $(".box_main").append($row.clone());
    }

    $(".left1").click(function() {
        $(".square").hover(function() {
            $(this).css("background", "#000");
        });
    });

    $(".left2").click(function() {
        $(".square").hover(function() {
            $(this).css("background", "#cfd8dc");
            $(this).fadeToggle("2500"); 
        });
    });

    $(".right1").click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });

    $(".right2").click(function() {
        $(".square").hover(function() {
            var rainbow = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "pink", "violet", "purple", "brown", "aqua", "gold"];
            var rand = rainbow[Math.floor(Math.random() * rainbow.length)];
            $(this).css("background", rand);
        });
    });

    $(".button_down").click(function() {
        var setup = prompt("enter a value between 1 and 64", "0");
        var rows = setup;
        var columns = setup;

        $(".row").height(40 / (16 / rows));

        $(".square").height(40 / (16 / columns));
        $(".square").height(40 / (16 / columns));
    });
});
```

CSS:

```css
.box_main {
    height: 640px;
    width: 640px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 15px;
}

.button_down {
    width: 300px;
}

.row {
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    background: #313131;
}

.square {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: should the grid be rebuild ? or re-arranged ? if re-arranged what would happen to the elements that do not fit ?

Comment: The whole point is that the total size of the grid shouldn't change so I'd like all the newly generated divs to fit into the initial 640*640 size.

Comment: so scrap the old square and create new ones to fill the main box?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a solution (*with some additional changes to avoid stacking hover events after each effect change*). Also i removed the rows wrapper as it is easier to accomplish with just correct sized elements and `float:left`

The basic idea is to make each square's dimensions `(100/columnsize)%`

```js
var rows = 16;
var columns = 16;
var $square = $("<div />", {
  class: 'square'
});

function fillGrid() {
  var box = $(".box_main").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows*columns; i++) {
    box.append($square.clone());
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  fillGrid();

  var hoverEffects = {
    black: function() {
      $(this).css("background", "#000")
    },
    colorFade: function() {
      $(this).css("background", "#cfd8dc");
      $(this).fadeToggle("2500");
    },
    rainbow: function() {
      var rainbow = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "pink", "violet", "purple", "brown", "aqua", "gold"];
      var rand = rainbow[Math.floor(Math.random() * rainbow.length)];
      $(this).css("background", rand);
    }
  };
  var activeEffect = $.noop;

  $(".left1").click(function() {activeEffect = hoverEffects.black});
  $(".left2").click(function() {activeEffect = hoverEffects.colorFade});
  $(".right1").click(function() {location.reload();});
  $(".right2").click(function() {activeEffect = hoverEffects.rainbow});

  // use delegated syntax so that we do not have to reapply handlers after
  // each grid rebuild
  $('.box_main').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.square',function() {
    activeEffect.apply(this);
  })

  $(".button_down").click(function() {
    var setup = prompt("enter a value between 1 and 64", "0");
    // use rows/columns without var to reuse the global variables
    rows = setup;
    columns = setup;
    fillGrid();
    $(".square").width(100/columns + '%');
    $(".square").height(100/rows + '%');
  });
});
```

```css
.box_main {
  height: 640px;
  width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 15px;
  background: #313131;
}
.button_down {
  width: 300px;
}
.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box_main"></div>
<button class="left1">black</button>
<button class="left2">faded</button>
<button class="button_down">resize</button>
<button class="right1">reload</button>
<button class="right2">rainbow</button>
```

Comment: Wow very helpful. Thank you for your work, you're a boss :)